# Select Query demand excesive resources

Tags: query, taxonomy, select

Good Morning:
I had detected that in a couple of times in the day I fond this query using a huge amount of resources in my wordpress server.
The query start to make a copy to disk of almost all the data base. And I have 250000 posts...
Does anybody have had the problem or know who nake the qery?
Thank you for your helping and scuse for my english!

```
SELECT *
FROM l4_sitio_term_relationships tr
INNER JOIN l4_sitio_posts p
        ON tr.object_id = p.ID
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND p.post_password = ''
        AND p.post_type = 'post'
INNER JOIN l4_sitio_term_taxonomy tt
        ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
        AND tt.taxonomy = 'category'
INNER JOIN l4_sitio_terms t
        ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
WHERE 1 = 1
```